# Parse null from dictionary in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I read a column from a db like this

```
row0:  {"colA":"valA", "colB":null}
row1:  {"colA":"valC", "colB":null}
```

Python read each row as string, which I want to convert to dictionary. However I am unable to parse this because of the null value. How can I convert the null into 'null' or NaN so that I can treat it and later explode into individual columns.

My final expected output is

```
colA  colB
valA  NaN
valC  NaN
```

Comment: Can you provide the query you're using along with the database ?

Comment: I doubt I can provide you the query and the details, but I am badly stuck on this

Comment: I am using TiDB as the database, when I retrieve my column it literally is translating into `{"colA":"valA", "colB":null}`, when I do type - class str

Comment: That is not possible. Please, if you cannot put the query here, print the result of the query in Python objects. `null` is not a Python object.

Comment: Please, provide an example of your input. You need to use json.loads() to convert your `JSON` string into valid Python objects.

Comment: Can you do `df.head(10).to_dict()` and paste the output in your question?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the data you are getting is in json format. So you can use [`pandas.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html#pandas.read_json) which will convert a `JSON` string to pandas object and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method of the `DataFrame` will fill `None` values with `np.nan`

```
>>> row = '{"colA":"valA", "colB":null}'
>>> pd.read_json(row, orient='index').T.fillna(np.nan)
   colA  colB
0  valA   NaN
```

Comment: Why not using `pd.DataFrame( [json.loads(row)] )`

Answer (score 0):

```
row0 = {"colA":"valA", "colB":float('nan')} #alt - np.nan
row1 =  {"colA":"valC", "colB":float('nan')}

pd.DataFrame([row0,row1])

   colA  colB
0  valA   NaN
1  valC   NaN
```

Comment: my colB contains values like that only - null, plain vanilla null

Comment: whats the type.. ? @Hardikgupta

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to take handle the None value

```py
import pandas as pd
l1 = '{"colA":"valA", "colB":null}'
l2 = '{"colA":"valC", "colB":null}'
lines = [l1, l2]
correct_dicts = [eval(li.replace(' null ', 'None')) for li in lines]
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'colA': [d.get('colA', None) for d in correct_dicts],
    'colB': [d.get('colB', None) for d in correct_dicts]
    }
    )
print(df)
print(correct_dicts)
```

It should be easy to generalise it to lines coming from a file.

**Edit**:
As pointed out by IMCoins in the comments this might end up messing up with string like `nullable_value_a`, this can certainly be fixed by some regexp but the simpler way as he suggested is to do

```py
import json
json.loads(YOUR_STRING)
```

Comment: What if I have `l1 = '{"colA" : "nullable_val_a", "colB" : null}'`

Comment: then you add `li.replace('null', 'None').replace("\"nullable_val_a\"", None)` and you should do the same for every string which is equivalent to None

Comment: My point was that `null` is a specific value, that exists to say there is no value. The `nullable_val_a` was a correct value, and shouldn't be altered. The correct way to handle `null`, which is a javascript object in this case (JSON notation), is to use the `json` helpers, such as `import json; json.loads(...)`

Comment: I did not know it, thanks! I just updated the question